# Translating Fallacy into Symbolic Logic

Tags: logic, logic-translation

I think I've read this, once.

1) If you don't like it here, then go somewhere else, or something like 2) You like it here, or you go somewhere else.

Something about this doesn't seem to make sense, to me.

I tried to translate it into Logic, Symbolic Logic, Predicate Logic to try to see where it doesn't seem to make sense.

I've got

1)

¬L→G

¬L

∴G

2)

L∨G

¬L

∴G

I think, I feel like, can't you not like it somewhere, and stay—(maybe to aim to work on things)? I do not think I can see where it makes no sense, logically. As of now, I have only feeling.

Comment: Both 1) and 2) are valid arguments. 1) is based on [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) and 2) on [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism).

Comment: I thought they seemed like Argument by Dismissal, or False Dilemma, fallacies? "You like it here, or you go somewhere else.", can't you not like it somewhere, and stay?

Comment: @saySay An argument is *sound* if it is both *valid* and the *premise justified*.  The arguments *are* valid.  You simply *don't agree* with their premises.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: He's asking about the disconnect between the fact that they are equivalent when simply (naively) translated into logic, and the fact that they don't seem to mean the same thing in English. See my answer that unpacks in detail the meaning of the English imperative.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Technically, the argument (that (1) implies (2)) is not valid, since (1) isn't even a declarative sentence as I explain in my answer. So the problem is not that the premise may be false, since there's no truth value to a command. If I say to you "Go away!", it is neither true nor false. At least, I don't think it makes sense to call the argument valid since it does not embed into logic in the naive way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from attempting to force an **imperative** sentence (command) in natural language to be a **declarative** sentence (factual statement). This is simply not allowed.

In classical first-order logic, all statements are declarative, so we don't have the ability to make imperative statements. If you want to stick to classical logic, you would have no choice but to first translate the imperative into a factual statement, and then express it in logic.

~~~

Original imperative:

> If you do not like it here, then go somewhere else.

Factual statement with nearly equivalent meaning but totally different tone:

> If you ever decide that you do not like it here, then after that you should go somewhere else.

Same factual statement in a form suitable for translation to classical first-order logic (where $X$ stands for "this place"):

> For any time $t$, if you decide at time $t$ "that you do not like $X$ at time $t$", then you should after time $t$ try making it so that you go after time $t$ to some place other than $X$.

(Note that I've interpreted the imperative not as a command. If it is a command then it does not mean "you should try to ..." but rather "I require you to ...").

Classical first-order logic translation with restricted quantification:
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

> $\forall t \in Times\ ( DecideAt(t,you,\ulcorner \neg LikeAt(t,you,X) \urcorner)$
>
> $\quad \imp ShouldTryAfter(t,you,\ulcorner \exists p \in Places\ ( p \ne X \land GoAfter(t,you,p) ) \urcorner) )$.

The "$\ulcorner \urcorner$" are used to quote statements, because stating what you think/feel about a statement is different from the truth of falsehood of the statement.

~~~

As you can see, it's not pretty! But literally that is how much detailed nuance the natural language sentence has in its meaning!

It is now easy to see that this is totally different from the other English sentence that you asked about, which is a very unnatural sentence but one that many people would interpret as a factual statement.

~~~

Original sentence:

> You like it here, or you go somewhere else.

One likely interpretation:

> Either you do not like it here at the present moment or you would go somewhere else.

Since the original sentence is already quite ambiguous, I will not attempt to translate it into logic.

~~~

However, let me show you what your original imperative is equivalent to, which is derived completely logically:

> $\neg \exists t \in Times\ ( DecideAt(t,you,\ulcorner \neg LikeAt(t,you,X) \urcorner)$
>
> $\quad \land \neg ShouldTryAfter(t,you,\ulcorner \exists p \in Places\ ( p \ne X \land GoAfter(t,you,p) ) \urcorner) )$.

(You cannot change the inner quoted stuff, just as "I do not believe that A is true" is not the same as "I believe that A is false"!)

This corresponds to the following English sentence:

> There is no time $t$ at which you will both decide that you do not like $X$ and you should not try after time $t$ to go to some place other than $X$.

Indeed, it states the same thing as the imperative, which you can slowly take the time to convince yourself after careful thought.

~~~

So the reason you feel differently about both sentences is that they are in fact saying completely different things. One cannot expect classical logic to capture easily natural language. To alleviate that problem, people have invented all sorts of other logics such as **modal logics**, named so because they were intended to try capturing modality in natural language, which are expressed in English via modal verbs like "shall", "should", "can", "could", "will", "would", "may", "might", "must", "ought to" and adverbs such as "possibly", "necessarily", "probably", "surely", "mostly", "slightly"...

Comment: So, from what I read here an imperative cannot translate into Logic, and that word should seems to add something to work on.

Comment: As for "If you don't like it here, then go somewhere else”, and, or, "You like it here, or you go somewhere else”, (if, when, translated into things usable for Logic), I’ve read it seems like a False Dilemma fallacy, or, Either-Or fallacy. Would you state they both seem valid? Can’t you not like it somewhere, and stay? It seems like it reads you do one thing, or another, when, can’t you do a third thing? I don’t think it makes logical sense, to me. How do you maybe prove this, maybe, fallacy using Logic, Symbolic Logic?

Comment: @saySay: I actually wanted to respond to your comment, but it isn't easy to really give a full answer. It's of a similar sort to a false dilemma, but not the same. In this question there are so many problems as I hope is clear through the explanation in my answer, that it is not really meaningful to classify it as one particular kind of fallacy. However, one main problem is **assuming that a command is a statement of fact**, which then means that "Go somewhere else!" is the same as "You will go somewhere else." (as a factual statement). Basically, commands have no truth value, that's all.

Comment: For any time t, if you decide at time t “that you do not like X at time t”, then you should after time t try making it so that you go after time t to some place other than X. What about using For any time t, if you decide at time t “that you do not like X at time t”, then you should stay and work on X.?

Comment: @saySay: What exactly are you asking? Your suggested statement in your last comment expresses an opinion/command, which is of course different from the one that my statement expresses. So? The original command in your question corresponds to mine, and not yours, so I do not see how yours is relevant to your question. I think you still make the very mistake I stated above. A command is **not a statement of fact**. If I tell you to do something, it's meaningless to say that my command is false just because you do not want to follow it. Neither is my command true.

Comment: I guess, things like 1) If you don't like it here, then go somewhere else, or something like 2) You like it here, or you go somewhere else., I've read, seem like a logical fallacy, false dilemma. I thought how to prove this, logically. It seemed you wrote it using Symbolic Logic. It seems they can get translated somewhat into Logic. I guess, it looks as you've used the imperative on 2).

Comment: So, I stated what about using For any time t, if you decide at time t “that you do not like X at time t”, then you should stay and work on X., instead of For any time t, if you decide at time t “that you do not like X at time t”, then you should after time t try making it so that you go after time t to some place other than X. instead. I guess I thought how to prove this, that 2) read like a false dilemma, and that how do I prove this, logically, and that, what if someone used what I stated. I think I see imperatives don’t have meaning, in Logic; and, they may have meaning.

Comment: Where, how would one prove other statements, or prove an imperative reads like a false dilemma. And, for 1), If you ever decide that you do not like it here, then after that you should go somewhere else. Can this get proven? It seems you didn’t use an imperative. The *should* seems strange. I don’t think I’ve seen a logical symbol stand as should.

Comment: @saySay: As I said already, an imperative cannot be expressed in most logical system, simply because it is **not a logical statement**. I also said in my answer that the sentence I wrote was a factual statement that had **nearly equivalent meaning but totally different tone**. It can potentially be proven/disproven if you have axioms governing all the predicates that it uses. If not, it's like you're asking whether you can prove a statement involving $f$ without telling me anything about $f$!

Comment: @saySay: Also, you should really go and study first-order logic and not try to handle natural language without any background in logic. I stated clearly in my last paragraph of my answer that people have invented modal logics to handle modals, and even included "should" in the list, but it seems you didn't read what I said properly. Either way, if you do not learn first-order logic first, you will be unable to either understand or use modal logic properly.

Comment: @saySay: And I do not know why on earth you insist on talking about "dilemma" and "fallacy". There is no logical fallacy when there isn't even meaning to begin with. Tell me, is "*X^Y~Z_W)" a fallacy? It isn't; it's just meaningless. Similarly, there is no relation between imperative sentences in English and sentences in first-order logic, and nothing you say about first-order sentences is at all relevant to imperative sentences. I never said the English sentence (2) is an imperative. **Read my answer properly**. Imperatives have meaning but not expressible in first-order logic, and that's it.

Comment: @saySay: The **specific** sentence that I gave as **one possible** meaning of your **ambiguous** english sentence (2) is for **you** to judge whether it is true or false (in the relevant context). If you think it is false, then you can say that it is a false dilemma. But it is silly to keep classifying illogical reasoning. Tell me, is "You are blue or you are red." a false dilemma? Arguably it is, but what good is it to know that it is?

Comment: No, no, I think I did read about should, and modal logic. I don’t think I’ve seen a symbol for it. I think I’ve seen □, and ◇. I think I see imperatives do not have meaning in Symbolic Logic. For, If you ever decide that you do not like it here, then after that you should go somewhere else., and For any time t, if you decide at time t "that you do not like X at time t", then you should after time t try making it so that you go after time t to some place other than X. I thought, why?

Comment: And for, Either you do not like it here at the present moment or you would go somewhere else., and There is no time t at which you will both decide that you do not like X and you should not try after time t to go to some place other than X. I thought how to prove this may not seem like a sole maybe usable statement. I aimed to try to see how to prove false dilemmas, to maybe try to maybe make visible that if someone said this, or maybe used this, this may not seem like a sole usable statement.

Comment: @saySay: Okay. There are different modal logics. Many of them use the same symbols such as □ and ◇, and some of them in use □ for "it should be that" ("it ought to be that"). But even here a lot of focus is on deontic logic concerning "it is obligatory that" ("morally should"), as the goal was to formalize ethics, so you may not find one that corresponds directly to the "should" in my sentence.

Comment: @saySay: I'm not sure I get what you're saying in the rest of your comments. If you're asking why I represented the original imperative that way, I believe that's the closest possible declarative statement in English. The imperative would be the meaning of the declarative one **plus** the conveying that it is the speaker's opinion/wish/command. That last part cannot fully be captured by most logics because logic is designed to model reasoning and not about influencing other people.

Comment: @saySay: I don't know what you mean by "how to prove false dilemmas". As I said, it's silly to classify things as false dilemmas. Just classify them as provable, disprovable or neither. If it is provable, then we must be able to give a (formal) proof. If it is not provable, then we cannot claim it to be true, and to prove that something is not provable depends heavily on what formal system we are talking about.

Comment: @saySay: For example first-order logic satisfies the completeness theorem and so provability of a sentence $φ$ is the same as entailment (every model satisfies $φ$), and so to prove non-provability of $φ$ we just need to prove the existence of a model that satisfies $\neg φ$. For sound formal systems in general, existence of a model not satisfying $φ$ implies non-provability, but the converse may not hold.

Comment: @saySay: In this question, it is in the first place meaningless to talk about (1) because it does not have a logical truth value. If you want to talk about (2) alone you can say it **should not** be provable in any reasonable formal system that correctly describes the real world, because in your **experience** of the real world it is **possible** to dislike a place but not go somewhere else. By the way, we shouldn't continue here. Reply to me in the chat-room if you want to ask some more.